# Regular expression to take 2 parts of a string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

**dir1\dir2\dir3\file.aspx.cs**(343,49): error CS0839: Argument missing [**C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\namespace.namespace.namespace.namespace\**project.csproj]

I've been trying for hours to create a regular expression to extract just 2 areas of this string. The bold areas are the parts I wish to capture.

I need to split this string into two seperate strings:

1. I'd like everything before the first "("
2. everything between the "[" and "]" but not including the "project.csproj"

For #1 the closest i've gotten is `(^.*\()` which will basically capture everything up to the first "(" (*including the bracket though which I don't want*)

For #2 the closest i've gotten is `(\[.*\])` which will basically capture everything inside the brackets (*including the brackets which i don't want*).

**Any of the words in the above string could change apart from ".csproj" "C:\" and ".cs"**

*Context: This is how MSBuild spits errors out when compiling. By capturing these two parts I can concatenate them to provide an exact link to the erroring file and open the file in Visual Studio automatically:*

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("devenv.exe","/edit path");
```

Comment: @vidit Why the rollback? That edit actually made the question more readable, IMO.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - because then it looses the bold areas, which *Jack* talks about in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern:

```
(^[^(]*).*\[(.*)project.csproj]$
```

Captures these groups:

1. `dir1\dir2\dir3\file.aspx.cs`
2. `C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\namespace.namespace.namespace.namespace\`

If the name `project.csproj` file could change, you can use this pattern instead:

```
(^[^(]*).*\[(.*\\)[^\\]*]$
```

This will match everything up to the last path fragment within the brackets.

Comment: For the 2nd part, 'project' could change. How can I incorporate that into your regex?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it works in http://regexpal.com/ I'm just about to test it in my application.

Comment: All works, I just removed the ^ and $ because there can be preceding / following text.

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now the parentheses aren't doing you any good. Just place them around the parts you are interested in:

```
^(.*)\(
```

and

```
\[(.*)\]
```

Now to exclude `projects.csproj` from the match, simply include it after the `.*`:

```
\[(.*)projects.csproj\]
```

Then `match.Groups(1)` will give you the desired string in each case (where `match` is your `Match` object).

If `projects.csproj` can be any file name (i.e. you only want everything until the last backslash, use:

```
\[(.*?)[^\\]*\]
```